# Older gas valve leaks when open

Tags: gas, fireplace

I have an older home that has a gas fire starter and the valve is mounted in the brick.  The pipe in the box was capped and we have no idea how long the fireplace was not used before we bought the house.  Maybe 30+ years.  We installed a vent-free gas log set and when we open the valve immediately smelled gas coming from the packing around the valve stem.  The valve has a packing nut holding the stem in but I can't find a single online reference to this particular valve. The sleeve that threads onto the valve that the key goes thru is approximately twice as large as a new 1/2" valve.  We'd like to avoid at almost all costs having to disrupt the brick to repair the valve.  Anyone recognize this valve?

[image]

Comment: What is on the other side of those blocks?  Blocks are usually 8 or 10 inches thick so that hole goes most of way though.  Will need to find a gas shut off valve before doing any work on repairing/replacing that valve.

Comment: I really can not recommend that amateurs do _anything_ with gas lines. The consequences of a mistake are unacceptable. It _is_ worth hiring a pro.

Comment: under that hex nut is the exterior seal (o-ring), that is not the shut off seal. Replacing it might stop the leak

Answer (score 2):

You should try to repack the valve yourself. First, with the gas supply isolated (shut off), try just tightening the packing nut and see if the leak stops. If it still leaks, you should be able to remove that packing nut and repack the packing gland.

On a valve that old it is likely that it *is not* an o-ring but likely some other composite material. You can get a twist of teflon packing string and put a loop or two on top of the existing packing and crank that nut down again, and try it.

If it still leaks, use tools to remove **all** the old packing, buy a few different sizes and shapes of packing washers (trim them with a knife to shape them if needed), throw a couple turns of the teflon string on top, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Most valves have two seals.

One inside at the bottom of the valve for open/close.

The second one on top to seal the shaft and stop the leaks to the outside.

In your case the top one is leaking after not been used for very long time.

You can try just tightening the hex nut (gently) and see if the leak stops,.

If not, you need to replace it (but closing the gas main first, then removing the hex nut and replacing the seal. Do not over-tighten it, it only needs to be compressed.